# How to close a usercontrol in the behind file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I am new to WPF so please understand:

I have a class of usercontrol that implements a screen (dialog) with a grid that contains controls. My code behind file performs a series of checks prior to opening the dialog. If the conditions aren't met, I want to destroy/exit/unload/close the usercontrol. I am using Windows and it seems that I cannot find the call to close the usercontrol. I read up on the questions that had answers such as closing from the parent... however when I try to find the parent via this.Parent, it returns null.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If your conditions aren't met, and you don't even show the usercontrol - don't initialize it.

If you can't avoid that, you have the option of calling Dispose() or letting the GC handle it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the parent from a usercontrol I use this

var parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);

But I agree with Andreas if the conditions are not met don't even load it.

A thought could you bind the grids contents remove the usercontrol from the bound object maybe .

Jim

Comment: Ooops yes, my usercontrol is embedded just inside the wpf app not in a grid.  Though I would have thought that in the Loaded event for the UserControl that still would gave worked.  That all said I think voddy's answer re adding the control as a child would be the best solution.  Jim

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have added your user control in the xaml. That is why you need to even worry about unloading it. Try loading it in the code instead. have a container in your xaml such as a stack panel to hold the user control.

And do not load it unless you conditions aren't met.

eg:

xaml;

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         >
    <Grid>
       <StackPanel x:Name="mypanel">                            
       </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

code;

```
 if(conditions are true) then
     Dim myusercontrol = New ucMyControl()
     Me.mypanel.Children.Add(myusercontrol)
 end if
```

Comment: can you be more specific please? I am new to WPF.. and you are correct, the user control is added in the xaml...

Comment: I have updated my answer. This code is working, I have it implemented and is working fine. If you get further errors pls post your code.

Comment: Oh man.. this one is going to be interesting. So I looked at my xaml and my xaml starts with: <UserControl x:Class="xxxxxx"xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:xxxxx"
    xmlns:editors="http://schemas.actiprosoftware.com/winfx/xaml/editor xmlns:shared="http://schemas.actiprosoftware.com/winfx/xaml/shared"
    Background="{StaticResource DefaultBackgroundColor}"          >

and if I try to add StackPanel, it says not found..

Error 1 The tag 'StackPanel' does not exist in XML names

Comment: I have updated my answer with more code as I feel you are not getting it. Stack panels is a container so we define them in body. I suggest you do some reading on WPF before jumping in to it. WPF is complex unless you start correctly and get the hang of it.